# Regular Expression to print only executable not full path

Tags: regex, text, expression, textwrangler

I have a set of key/value pairs that lists executables using the fully qualified name as follows:

```
  ["exec"] = "/share/home/00288/tg455591/NAMD_2.8b3/NAMD_2.8b3_Linux-x86_64-MVAPICH-Intel-Ranger/namd2",
```

However, I would like to take out the directory location and only print the executable, such as the following:

```
  ["exec"] = "namd2",
```

How can I construct a regular expression to make this change?  Keep in mind all the executables in the file are different, but they have similar format.  The size of the file is approximately 6000 lines.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think `[^/]*$` will match it, but it depends on the flavor of regex. What tool are you using?

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Why don't you just split on `/`?

Comment: I am using grep in the TextWrangler application

Comment: I don't split on the / because the number of / varies from line to line

Comment: For clarification, you need `"/share/home/00288/tg455591/NAMD_2.8b3/NAMD_2.8b3_Linux-x86_64-MVAPICH-Intel-Ranger/namd2"` to match to `namd2` only, isn't it? Do you have to match the _key_ `["exec"]` as well?

Comment: @amber4478 - `$array = explode('/', $string); $exec = end($array);`

Comment: Yes I need the key as well so ["exec"] = "namd2"

Comment: Would you consider using `sed` instead?

Comment: That would be OK.  I am using TextWrangler or TextMate, but it wouldn't really be an issue to open a terminal and use sed

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression did the trick:

```
(?<=\["exec"\] = ").+?(?=[^/]+?(?:\.\w+)?")
```

Replace with:

```
\1\2
```

Answer (score 1):

try this to find :

```
(?<="exec"] = ")[^"]*?/([^/"]+)(?=")
```

and this to replace :

```
\1
```

(or $1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, this `sed` command will do the trick:

```
sed 's|= .*/|= "|'
```

Comment: sed 's|= .*/|= "\' lariatData-sgeT-2012-05-01_2.lua
sed: 1: "s|= .*/|= "\": unterminated substitute in regular expression  is the error I get when I try the sed command

Comment: @amber4478: It's `"|'`, not `"\'`.